# In django model class, is ManyToManyField directional?

Tags: django, django-models

Suppose I have two model classes:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    tag = models.ManyToManyField('Tags')

class Tags(models.Model):
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

And

```
class Project(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Tags(models.Model):
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    projects = models.ManyToManyField(Project)
```

Are these two implementations equivalent?
Or do I need to have `ManyToManyField` declared in both of the classes?
How about `OneToOneField`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only difference in these implementations is the name of the linking table: in the first, it will be called "myapp_project_tags" and in the second "myapp_tags_project". In either case, you can override that by explicitly defining a `through` model.

OneToOneFields are different, since they are actually fields on a model, so they have to live on one side or the other.